# How do you conditionally include a framework in an Xcode project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Is it possible to have a single Xcode project (and ideally a single target) that will conditionally include frameworks when built against a certain version of OS X / Xcode but not include those frameworks when built against another version?

I'd like to begin adding support for El Capitan to an application I'm working on but some of the support I have in mind requires linking against frameworks that are not present in Yosemite. Is there a way to configure an Xcode project so that the same project can be built under 10.11 / Xcode 7 with the frameworks but also built under 10.10 / Xcode 6 without the frameworks (and without throwing an error)?

I'm aware of how to check for the existence of a class or method at runtime, but it's not clear to me how I control the framework linking without creating a second Xcode project, a second source control branch or always building against Xcode 7 (none of which I want to do, yet).

Answer (score 2):

The "other version" would essentially be another `target` — it's setup this way to do precisely what you're asking about. A basic example would be just a matter of right-clicking on your original target and selecting `duplicate` from the current targets; then make whatever changes to linking frameworks within the `Build Phases` section.

### Targets

In Build Phases you'll notice I've linked three frameworks to my
original target:

[image: original]

> After right-clicking on the original target and creating a duplicate
>   I'm able to link it differently:

[image]

The duplicate version of MyApp uses the same classes and headers as the original with the exception of those that require the excluded frameworks. It's also possible to import different frameworks, change things such as the `Deployment Target` (e.g. build for different versions of `OS X`), or perhaps which `SDK` each might use, etc.

Once you're more familiar with the standard build process you can then create custom build scripts to handle specialized tasks like keeping the target names the same or even creating installer packages — anything is possible.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping there was a way to not have to create a second target so that I didn't have to worry about keeping two separate targets in sync. (WRT to adding/removing files, common build settings, etc...)

Comment: If you didn't have a second target though how else would expect to do it? The build settings should be in sync if you utilize the variables within the build settings. Once you've got the build configurations done for your targets you can also use `schemes` to further customize every aspect of your targets build as well, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Well that's exactly what I was interested in, whether or not there is some sort of Xcode or build trick that maybe involved xcconfig files, pre-build scripts, conditional build settings, etc., that didn't require a second target. (ex: Can an xcconfig file detect that it's building under Xcode 7 / 10.11 and conditionally link in a framework?) If not, can a build phase be added that runs a script to check what's being built and modify the the build environment? Maybe not, but that's what I was curious about.